# Debugger always saves my project and I can't step back

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I often need to return to a previous milestone. 
There is a vicious cycle: my error is revealed only during debugging, but I can't step back because the debugger has saved my project.

In simple projects I always used to make a copy of my cpp file (just keep ctrl and drug your file a bit).

But now projects has become more complicated (with header files). 
I have tried to use save solution as. But it seems as if it is just renaming the sln file without making a copy of the whole project.

So, what shall I do? Copy the whole project as I did with the file?

The question seems a bit clumsy but it really troubles me: what elegant decision is there?

Comment: You can still undo changes with Ctrl-Z after a file has been saved.

Comment: I'm under the impression that questions about workflow belong on programmers.se?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vs 2010, you can disable saving on build event from Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Build and Run

Comment: Thank you. That will be fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use software versioning systems like SVN or Git to undo the savings and return to previous point in your project, also there are some extensions for visual studio like [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) and [Gitextention](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) that you can use.